# grails 3 gsp using domain object constraints failing

Tags: grails, grails3

In grails 2 we were able to reference the domain object constraints in a gsp as to keep the html 5 configration dry.  On grails 3 (tried both 3.1.10 and 3.2.0.RC1) I get an error for code I tested in grails 2 successfully.  I am trying to reference the constraint matches in the attribute phone and use that for the HTML 5 pattern.  The scaffolding use to generate this code but for Grails 3 the scaffolding generates use the fields plugin so I cannot see that code.  Any ideas?

Here is the domain object code:

```
class Disruption {

static constraints = {
    phone(matches:/^[0-9]{10}$/, nullable:true)
    email(email:true, nullable:false)
}

String name
String phone
String email
```

Here is the gsp code:

```
    <div class="form-group ${hasErrors(bean: disruption, field: 'phone', 'error')}">
    <label for="phone" class="control-label col-sm-3">
        Phone
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <g:textField name="phone" style="width: 7em" class="form-control" title="Phone 10 digits" pattern="${disruption.constraints.phone.matches}" maxlength="10" placeholder="##########" value="${disruption.phone}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the exception:

URI
    /disruption/create
Class
    java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
    Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/disruption/create.gsp:92] Error executing tag : Error evaluating expression [disruption.constraints.phone.matches] on line [58]: Cannot get property 'phone' on null object
Caused by
    Cannot get property 'phone' on null object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Domain Objects need to use the constrainedProperties and Command Object need to use the constraintsMap see examples below.

```
            <g:textField name="phone" style="width: 7em" class="form-control" title="Phone 10 digits" pattern="${disruption.constrainedProperties.phone.matches}" maxlength="10" placeholder="##########" value="${disruption?.phone}"/>
```

OR for Command Objects

```
            <g:textField name="phone" style="width: 7em" class="form-control" title="Phone 10 digits" pattern="${searchCommand.constraintsMap.phone.matches}" maxlength="10" placeholder="##########" value="${searchCommand?.phone}"/>
```